# Convert equation system in to one ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I tried with a few algebraic manipulations with no success.
for the system:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -5 \\ -7 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Tried 
$x_{1}'=x_{2}$ thus from first equation I get $x_{2}=4x_{1}-5x_{2}$
and then replacing the $x_{2}$ in second equation with $\frac{2}{3}x_{1}$ and the result become $y''=-9y$.

This is not the final answer for some reason, They didn't do any example in class and my logic isn't working here...

Comment: But $x_1'$ isn't $x_2$, it's $4x_1-5x_2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $x'=Ax$ the $2\times2$ matrix $A$ has a characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(A-λI)=λ^2-tr(A)λ+\det(A).$$
By Cayley-Hamilton, $χ_A(A)=0$ and thus also
$$
x''-{\rm tr}(A)x'+\det(A)x=χ_A(D)x=χ_A(A)x=0,
$$
here
$$
0=x_k''-x_k'-47x_k,~~k=1,2.
$$

Comment: can you explain this part?$0=χ_A(A)x=x''-tr(A)x'+\det(A)x,$ I understand that $\chi_A(A)=0$ but the notation of $\chi_A(A)x$ I'm not familiar

Comment: It comes from $\chi_A(D)x=\chi_A(A)x=0$, and then inserting what the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are in this case.